# Optional enum in swift from objective-c

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a protocol defined in objective-c. It has a property which is an enum.
I want to create a swift class that implements this protocol and I want the swift class to have the enum field optional.
I can't use `nullable` annotation for enum types.
How to work around this issue?

Comment: Maybe with using a "MyEnum.Unset" which would represent the "unknown" case and pass over the case?

Comment: How are you creating the Enums? In swift? or in Objective-c?

Comment: In objective-c with NS_ENUM macro

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Enums in Objective-C are never `nil` because they always default to `0` as they are not reference types.

Thus, you cannot have the property never-`nil` to implement the protocol while making it optional (e.g. nullable) in swift.

If you need the property nullable nullable sometimes, then you probably have to redesign your architecture (e.g. the hierarchy of protocols to have one where it is optional).

Answer (score 0):

If you want your field to be optional, then you can give it a default value. Not really sure how your code looks like but something like this should work:

```
func mySwiftMethod(firstParameter: String, enumParameter: MyEnum = MyEnumDefaultValue)
```

This way, the swift calls can replace the parameter with the default value and you dont have to include it. However, that value cannot be nil because the enumeration is actually an `NSInteger` value.

Hope this helps :)